# Azure Function calling an external REST API, 504 Server Error after 4 mins

Tags: azure, azure-functions

As title, an **504 Server Error** timeout occurs after **calling an external REST API** with Azure Function for **4 mins** .

Just encounter this timeout issue, not sure where can I find a configuration to change this 4 mins timeout, any help with be greatly appreciated.

**Info:**

- Azure plan: Premium
- Runtime: NodeJS 12
- Configuration: all timeout related are default

**Steps to reproduce:**

[1]  Create an external API like so:

```
<?php
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 500);
set_time_limit(0); 
$timeout = (int) $_REQUEST["time"]; 
sleep($timeout);
echo "Sleep for :".$timeout;
```

[2] HttpTrigger:

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    let errorText = " | Error: ";
    let responseText = " | Response: ";
    try {
        let timeout = 60 * 21;// In seconds
        const response = await axios.get('http://www.example.com/bigjob.php?time=' + timeout);
        responseText += response.data;

    } catch (error) {
        errorText += String(error);
    }

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: `A temp Http trigger for testing ${responseText} ${errorText}`
    };
    return;
};
```

After running for exactly 4 mins, the **HTTPTrigger** will stop, and the page will shows:

---

### **Server Error.**

There was an unexpected error in the request processing.

---

With the **Server Error** text colored in green.

Comment: While it might seems like this is an issue of HttpTrigger, see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout. However, I have also tried replacing HttpTrigger with an Service Bus trigger, still the same issue with 4 mins max timeout.

Comment: I found something, maybe the Azure Function timeout is related to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-230-seconds
If so, I don't think there is anything we can do to fix this.... Sad time

Comment: use diagnose and solve to identify the problem. Seems to me you're reaching the max number of tcp connections

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this happen even if I am making a single HTTP call, so I don't think is related to max number of tcp connections.

Comment: there must be something in your function that keeps running. Try locally first

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, but I specifically made a new function app, with a new App Service Plan, only a single HttpTrigger, as shown above. Therefor, unlikely other process affecting my Azure Function. I do tried locally and its work, and this 4 mins timeout issue only occurs when the Azure Function is deployed to cloud. Thanks.